# Start activity from another activity?

Tags: android, authentication, android-activity, android-dialog

I want in my application this functionality:

When i start my app

```
-check if there is interne access : if yes {
                                        start LogInActivity { if login is succesfull
                                                              dialog:"synced!" for 3second
                                                             else
                                                               dialog:"no synced!" for 3second
                                                                  }
                                    }
                                        dialog:"no synced!"
                                        startMainActivity
```

I want the first activity just to performs checks.Not to be visible and if there is internet
then forward to login Activity else login to Main activity

This is because i want my app to be used without interner.But for the logged users it will download from web service some information to be stored in Shared Preferences.Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a third activity that starts first and on the onCreate of that activity you run your code and call other activity.

Also you could show a splash screen on this third activity, while you decide which activity to show.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to create a small function which checks both for wifi and mobile net as follows :-

```
/**
 * Function to check whether internet connection is available or not
 * 
 * @return true - if net is available
 */
public boolean haveNetworkConnection() {
    mHaveConnectedWifi = false;
    mHaveConnectedMobile = false;

    mConnectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    mNetworkInfo = mConnectivityManager.getAllNetworkInfo();

    for (NetworkInfo mNetInfo : mNetworkInfo) {
        if (mNetInfo.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
            if (mNetInfo.isConnected())
                mHaveConnectedWifi = true;
        if (mNetInfo.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
            if (mNetInfo.isConnected())
                mHaveConnectedMobile = true;
    }
    return mHaveConnectedWifi || mHaveConnectedMobile;
}
```

Now in your code just do :-

```
if(haveNetworkConnection){
// do something
}else{
    // no internet
}
```

The advantage is that we are checking for both wifi and mobile net...

Hope the explanation was useful....

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to either use `startActivity()` or `startActivityForResult()`.

The advantage of `startActivityForResult()` is that you can receive data back from the activity you started, upon its completion.

Answer (score 0):

To launch your other activity:

```
if(connection/login fails){

                    Intent loginfailed = new Intent(MainActivity.this, loginfailedactivity.class);
                    startActivity(loginfailed);
      }

    else {.....}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to make sure there was a wifi connection:

```
private void checkWifiConnection(String menuUrl){

    ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

    if(mWifi.isConnected()){
        LoadJSON lJs = new LoadJSON(); 
        lJs.execute(menuUrl); 
    } else {
        AlertDialog.Builder ab = new AlertDialog.Builder(context); 
        ab.setCancelable(true);
        ab.setTitle("No Connection"); 
        ab.setMessage("Your device is currently not connected to the Internet, please check your connection and launch the app again."); 
        ab.setInverseBackgroundForced(true); 
        ab.setPositiveButton("Okay", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss(); 
                MainActivity.this.finish(); 


            }
        }); 

        AlertDialog alert =  ab.create(); 
        alert.show(); 


    }
```

You could insert an `Intent` call in the `if` statement that launches your `Activity`